# Add ints to listview for sorting

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview and I am trying to sort it based on a column. I have the columnclick event etc working, and it sorts, but I have the following problem:

I can't seem to add items to the listview as integers. This is a problem as if I have a column of ints that I had to use `ToString()` on, the sort puts 10 ahead of 2.

Does anyone know how I can add items as int's so that the sort has the desired functionality. Also, not all columns are int, there are some string columns and I'd like the sort to work on those too.

For reference, I used the following tutorial for the sort code: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401

Cheers

Comment: Use a DataGridView instead. It does not require the bound data to be `ToString()`'d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if the selected column has numbers.
Write this in the compare function

```
            int intX = 0, intY = 0;
            if(int.TryParse(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, out intX)
                && int.TryParse(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, out intY))
            {
                return intX.CompareTo(inty);
            }
```

Maybe is problem if some column contains numbers and text.

Comment: Thanks, combined this (Int32.TryParse) with the code in the tutorial and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a sorter class that implements IComparer and assign it to the ListViewItemSorter property of the ListView.

IComparer has a method Compare. Two ListViewItem instances are passed to that method. You need to read the column value, then parse it to int and return the correct comparison result (int based instead of string based).

You can create your own ListViewItem class that creates the string value for the column but also holds the original int value to avoid the int.Parse call in the comparer.

Untested example:

```
public class MyItemComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        ListViewItem xItem = (ListViewItem)x;
        ListViewItem yItem = (ListViewItem)y;

        int a = int.Parse(xItem.SubItems[0]);
        int b = int.Parse(yItem.SubItems[0]);
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}
```